# Move adjacent divs smoothly when a div hides

Tags: jquery, css, html, transition

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2un99/2/)

When I click on the green div, everything hides, but the green div is jerky, as in, it comes right next to the first green div with a jerky motion. Is it possible to smooth transit, so that it slides and takes its places right next to the first green div?

JS:

```
$('.green').click(function(){
    $('.others').fadeOut();
});
```

CSS:

```
.green{ background:green; padding:10px; margin:10px; }
.red{ background:red; padding:10px; margin:10px; }
.blue{ background:blue; padding:10px; margin:10px; }
.green:hover{ cursor:pointer;}
.fade{display:none; opacity:0;}
div{ float:left; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="red others"></div>
<div class="blue others"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="red others"></div>
<div class="blue others"></div>
```

Comment: I believe you'd need absolute positioning, and then make each div 'slide' up via jQuery animation on it's position based on the new space available from the last div collapsing. See the `animate()` function here: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Is there no other way around it without the use of position:absolute? This is a responsive design, so positioning the elements will create issues.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you could switch your `fadeout()` with `hide()`

```
$('.green').click(function(){
$('.others').hide(300);


});
```

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2un99/4/) updated.

Comment: This is a good answer. With `$('.others').hide(800);` it looks really smooth.

Comment: @Urbz.. Yes it does ;) Happy Friday!!

Comment: @Mike.. Happy friday to you too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.green').click(function(){
    $('.others').animate({
        "margin-left":0,
        "margin-right":0,
        "padding-left":0,
        "padding-right":0,
        width:0,
    }, 300);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2un99/5/

Do animation, clear just margins and paddings, and animate width to 0, so adjecent divs move along

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to remove opacity & size, then hide it.

```
$('.green').click(function(){
    $('.others').animate({'opacity':0},200,function(){
        $(this).animate({'width':0},200,function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

If you divs are below each other you can animate `height` to `zero(0)`.

Comment: Nothing happens when I replace this function in the fiddle.

Comment: @Harmeet sorry one ) bracket was missing. Now check. Change time of 200 milliseconds as per your need

Comment: it works just like the one I originally posted : http://jsfiddle.net/2un99/2/

NO change.

Comment: @Harmeet That becuase you have created your divs using padding & margin, I assumed you are using width/height. Thus you have to animate padding & margin also. See this http://jsfiddle.net/2un99/10/

Comment: @rohanAM Thanks! Your solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.green').click(function(){
    $('.others').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

OR

```
this:$('.green').click(function(){ $('.others').hide("literal"); });
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question, the second green div comes in and gets placed beside the first green div with a jerk. The fade time is not an issue here.

Comment: In that case you can try this:$('.green').click(function(){
$('.others').hide("literal");
});